# How do I stop Geolocation from submitting twice?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, geolocation

I am building a crime alert website and I want the user's longitude and latitude to be extracted once the user submits a new alert. Instead, it is submitting twice returing both lat and lng with value and the other without value.

I wanted it to return this:

```
lucas posted a crime alert!
Alert!!! cv !!!

Crime reported from Ogbia, Bayelsa

Crime coordinates: Longitude 3.325952 | Latitude 6.599475

Category: c

March 9, 2023, 1:53 p.m.
```

Instead, it is submitting twice like this:

```
lucas posted a crime alert!
Alert!!! cv !!!

Crime reported from Ogbia, Bayelsa

Crime coordinates: Longitude 3.325952 | Latitude 6.599475

Category: c

March 9, 2023, 1:53 p.m.

lucas posted a crime alert!
Alert!!! cv !!!

Crime reported from Ogbia, Bayelsa

Crime coordinates: Longitude None | Latitude None

Category: c

March 9, 2023, 1:53 p.m.
```

My Views:

```
def new_alert(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST.get("content")
        state = request.POST.get("state")
        lga = request.POST.get("lga")
        category = request.POST.get("category")
        current_user = request.user
        lat = request.POST.get("lat")
        lng = request.POST.get("lng")
        # Create a new alert
        new_alert = Alert(content=content, state=state, lga=lga, user=current_user, category=category, latitude=lat, longitude=lng)
        new_alert.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("all_alerts"))
    else:
        return render(request, "new_alert.html")
```

My Javascript:

```
<script>
  function getLocation() {`your text`
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      // Display confirmation prompt
      if (confirm("Allow this website to access your location?")) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendLocation);
      } else {
        alert("Location access denied.");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }

  function sendLocation(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log("Sending data: ", { lat: lat, lng: lng });

    // Get the CSRF token from the form
    var csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

    // Get the form data using FormData
    var form_data = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form-id'));

    // Add the lat and lng values to the form data
    form_data.append('lat', lat);
    form_data.append('lng', lng);

    // Send the AJAX request with the form data
    $.ajax({
      url: 'new_alert',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form_data,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Fill the fields before submitting Alert');
      }
    });
  }


</script>
```

My HTML(I removed the items in the dropdown so it does't get too long here):

```
<form id="form-id" action="{% url 'new_alert' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea id="create-post-text" name="content" placeholder="Report crime" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Where Are You Reporting From?</label>
      
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">LGA of Origin</label>
        <select name="lga" id="lga" class="form-control select-lga" required>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="category" placeholder="Specify a category. For example, murder, theft, vandalism, etc" required>
    </div>

    <button onclick="getLocation()" class="btn btn-success" id="sendLocation">Alert!</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you want the form to have an action given that the action is also does via JS?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the duplication of alert submissions, where the first submission contains latitude and longitude values but the second submission does not. This can be caused by the function submitAlert(), which sends the form data but does not include the location information. To fix the issue, you can modify the submitAlert():

function submitAlert() {

```
// Get the CSRF token from the form
var csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

// Get the form data using FormData
var form_data = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form-id'));

// Get the latitude and longitude values from the current position
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    // Add the lat and lng values to the form data
    form_data.append('lat', lat);
    form_data.append('lng', lng);

    // Send the AJAX request with the form data
    $.ajax({
        url: 'new_alert',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('Fill the fields before submitting Alert');
        }
    });
}, function(error) {
    alert('Failed to get location information');
});
```

}

Comment: I have edited the code, I am still getting the same result like this:

lucas posted a crime alert!
Alert!!! f !!!

Crime reported from Tafawa Balewa, Bauchi

Crime coordinates: Longitude None | Latitude None

Category: c

March 9, 2023, 8:08 p.m.

lucas posted a crime alert!
Alert!!! f !!!

Crime reported from Tafawa Balewa, Bauchi

Crime coordinates: Longitude 3.325952 | Latitude 6.576538

Category: c

March 9, 2023, 8:08 p.m.